# Работа с UITableView, отступ между row/

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

Как сделать отступ между row в таблице? Нашел только отступ между section. Надо, чтобы на элементы можно было нажимать. Я сделал так: cell сделал с учетом отступа, на нее кинул вьюху меньшего размера, а на вьюху кинул кнопку. Но из-за кнопки таблица не листается.

Прикрепил скрин прототипа ячейки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, а то я прям застрял на этом

[image: фото прототипа ячейки]

Comment: Не понял, как кнопка связана с отсутствующим скроллом в таблице?

Answer (score 1):

Вы все правильно делаете с отступом, это верный подход. Понятия "расстояние между ячейками" в ios просто нет (можно только регулировать, будет ли разделитель между ними, но он фиксированной высоты и влиять можно только на его стиль).

Вторая проблема с тем, что кнопка в ячейке похищает прокрутку, лечится примерно так: `self.tableView.scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = YES;` либо это же можно задать в визуальном редакторе, на таблице свойство называется "Cancellable content touches" - она должна быть включена.

Если это не поможет, нужно создать новый класс, наследованный от UITableView, и назначить его в виз. редакторе на вашу таблицу:

```
@interface MyTableView: UITableView
@end

@implementation MyTableView
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
    return YES;
}
```

Этими двумя настройками мы говорим scrollview таблицы, может ли она отменять уже активные тачи, и забирать их себе.